# scanf ignore the enter key and do not change the value of the variable

Tags: c, scanf

I am developing a software in C and I need to read a whole number, but if the user presses the "enter" key, the scanf should ignore and not modify the current value of the variable. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void) {

    int a = 5;
    
    printf("\nenter an integer value for the variable 'a': ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    
    printf("\n the value of variable 'a' is: %d", a);
    //if the user presses the enter key the output is: 5
    
    //if the user enters number 7 the output is: 7
   
}
```

thanks

Comment: `scanf` will not ignore it. You can try using `fgets()` and then apply `sscanf()` to that string and if it does not return `1` then the string was "empty" (apart from a newline) or did not contain a convertible number.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &a);` does not return with only an enter key pressed, it is still waiting for non-white-space input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void) {
    
    int a = 5;
    char number[2]; 
    
    printf("\nenter a value for the variable 'number': ");
    
    fgets(number, 2, stdin); 
    
    if(sscanf(number, "%d")>0){
        a = atoi(number);
    }
    
    printf("variable 'a' is: %d\n", a); 
 
}
```

Comment: I suggest you make `char number[2];` rather larger. This 2-character array can hold one digit and the string terminator. So if you enter that single digit the newline which `fgets()` would also like to capture will remain in the input buffer, and cause an "empty" string to be read at it next usage. If you are entering a 32-bit integer I suggest `char number[16];`

Comment: Also `if(sscanf(number, "%d")>0)` is lacking one argument, it should be `if(sscanf(number, "%d", &a) == 1)` and delete the `atoi()`.

Answer (score 1):

Always check the result of scanf.

In your case:

```
if(scanf("%d", &a) != 1)
    printf("\nThe scanf was not successful\nThe value of the `a` was not changed\n");
```

When `scanf` was not successful the variable is not changed.

https://godbolt.org/z/GcY51W

Comment: `scan()` will not return until you enter some data. You can't detect a single <Enter> this way.